# How to insert a new function (method) into class?

Tags: c#

Making the transition from VB.NET to C# 2008.  I have really learned a lot, but want to ask a few questions.

When I create dynamic controls, I need to add events to them.  So I need to insert these events into my programs.  IE...

Create a `TextBox`, then need to add a `KeyUp` event.  What I do now is drop a text box on my form, go to its events, double click on the event I want, then rename the function to what I want, and delete the text box from the form.

Is there no insert new function (by menu or right click menu?) Or is it possible to learn all the params?  object sender pretty easy, but the `EventArgs` changes.

TIA :} DPRoberts

Comment: Is this WebForms or WinForms? Also, are you familiar with delegates?

Comment: F12 key is your friend. Please feel free to push it.

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser F1 is another alternative (also RTFM is not really acceptable approach anymore, so maybe your route of digging through metadata/decompiled code is more modern).

Comment: I am using WinForms.  F1 opens MS Help, and unlikely to help me if 2 hours of GOOGLE has not given an answer. {Also in my 28 years of using MS products the only thing I have learned from MS help, is DONT use MS help!}  F12 take you to the definition of a variable/function, this is way easier with a right-click BTW.  So I am back to square one, how to insert the event function for a dynamically created control.  :} DPRoberts

Answer (score 0):

You might have to learn about [delegates](http://www.dotnetperls.com/delegate) and [lambda expressions](http://www.dotnetperls.com/lambda) for this.

Here is an example this might help.

```
        for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
        {
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Name = "tb1";
            tb.Click += (obj, evntArgs) =>
            {
                //This is your click event code for this text
            };
        }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: On the line tb.Click += (obj, evntArgs) => how did you know to use evntArgs(sp?).  Did you have this memorized or is there a list?  :} DPRoberts

Comment: @DPRoberts actually, the IntelliSense will help you to create your event handler when you press Tab after +=[space] as for what events are available, once you put "tb." Then the IntelliSense will start populating for you too. So memory work is minimum... This is true for VS2010 onwards at least..

Comment: @DPRoberts the lion's share of events have the delegate type EventHandler, which takes an EventArgs type for the event args. For an example of something which uses a different type check out the [CellValueChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx)  event. Note the delegate type for that event is DataGridViewCellEventHandler, not the standard EventHandler. And so, it has the custom DataGridViewCellEventArgs, which obviously carries some meta data. You do not need to learn all the args. The doco has it all layed out.

Comment: @DPRoberts here evntArgs is just the name of the parameter, not it's type, he could have typed banana or moon it would've been the same result, the type is inffered by the compiler as the lambda method is assigned to the click handler and the compiler picks arguments that would match

Answer (score 0):

I hope I doing this right, I do not use forums and the like very often.  But my reply was to complicated to do as a comment.

The last few comments were at least close to what I need.  I am going to put some code here to help with the explanation.  BUT!!! this is not a coding question, so any talk about it will not help me!  This is an IDE question I am looking for a menu item or toolbar button that allow me to insert a new function (that already knows the correct params for an event.)  OK here is a live example:

```
TextBox txtTemp = new TextBox();
txtTemp.KeyUp += fnKeyUp_txtQtySent;

txtTemp.Font = fArial10;
txtTemp.Location = new Point(nXPos, nYPos);
txtTemp.Tag = sTag;
txtTemp.Text = dbRDR.GetInt32(1).ToString();
txtTemp.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
txtTemp.Width = 48;
pnlContracts_Open.Controls.Add(txtTemp);
```

Now the next step is to create/insert  a fnKeyUp_txtQtySent function/method.  I currently do it in one of 2 ways, cut/paste from another KeyUp event OR the 5-6 step way I explained above.  Is there a a menu path that will do this IE (Insert > Event > TextBox > KeyUp.  Then a blank KeyUp event is inserted ready to be renamed and coded.

Thanks ALL for the efforts, I was a VB 3,4,5,6 programmer for years and took a break, to come back to .NET about 6 years ago.  So this is one of those few things I have not learned how to do correctly.

:} DPR

Comment: The thing is you probably should (and please try to take this as friendly advice, i'm not trying to be mean but constructive) "learn" .net, not try to learn tiny bits independantly. After 6 years of .net you shouldn't be having trouble with events as it's one of the fairly basic features of the language. I strongly suggest you pick up a book on .net and read it front to back (i suggest pro c# 5.0 and the .net 4.5 Framework, it's big but exhaustive and if you already know how to do most things you need you can stick to just reading the language part and leaving out the end of the book)

Comment: As for a simple way to create that method, don't do it by hand, as soon as you've typed txtTemp.KeyUp+= you should be able to hit tab twice and end up with the method you need. Even going from the code as it is now you should be able to right click on the fnKeyUp_txtQtySent and chose generate method, visual studio will figure out the parameters for you.

Comment: Thank you Ronan, you finally got it in you last few words,  OK now it looks like I have a disconnect in my IDE, I am using 2008 Express.  I do not see a generate method option.  Is this only in the PRO edition?  Does anyone know?  :} DPR

Answer (score 0):

Hope to help with this. If I understand right, you want to create a handler "automagically" so that you can receive the proper event arguments.

When you are typing the name of the object and then the name of the event, followed by `+=`:

`TextBox.KeyUp +=` <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>

**Press tab twice** as soon as you finish the `+=` part. This will create a handler method with the correct argument types.

Another trick os to type, say:

```
TextBox.KeyUp += (a, b) => { //this is an empty function block }
```

And then put your mouse over `a` and/or `b` to see their tooltips with their inferred types. Usually `a` is `object` (the sender of the event) and `b` is some subclass of `EventArgs`, but a lot of times you won't even need to use the arguments anyway.

And [here you have a step-by-step](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z57dxz2(v=vs.90).aspx) guide on how to implement the event and the handler, in case you need.

Comment: Thank you Helton, your link is a lot of what to do, I need how to do.  I really like that trick you mentioned I guess that would be a third way.  But there must be a way to do it in the IDE.  I think I am really close with Ronin's comment above.  Can you please take a look and see if you can answer that question.  :} DPR

Comment: "do it in the IDE" means typing "+=" after the event name and hitting tab twice. have you already tried it? It will create a code template of the method for you! That's how it's done, that's how _everyone_ does that in Visual Studio!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for trying, special thanks to Ronan!  With the keywords "Generate Method" from Ronan, I found what I needed.  It appears that VS 2008 does not have the short cuts keys ctrl + K + M or a right click menu to do this.  I installed VS 2012 and they were both there.

Because I am changing languages VB to C#, it will make it easy to switch versions also.  It was amazing to see it work, after years of cut/paste.  I found a web page with a list of shortcuts, and the one mentioned above does not appear in 2015, 2012 and 2013 only.

Thanks again, and I considered the question answered.

:} DPRoberts